# Blocked access to batch file

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, permissions, sql-server-agent

I am unable to execute batch files to copy backups from SQL Server 2008 R2 hosted on Windows 2008 R2 to a file share.

Error:

> Access denied

SQL Server Agent service has full control on the soure and destination folders.

This only happens in Windows Server 2008 R2 on my production environment, suspecting additional security controls on Windows Server 2008 causing this issue.

Comment: `access denied` means the account that is trying to access dont have access to the file share. Check security settings or with your windows Admin.

Comment: What account is the SQL Server Agent service logging in as? Have *you* logged in as that user and verified that they do have rights to the file share?

Comment: Hi Aaron,Thanks for the reply, yes i did verify the permissions it can able to write it with the account. Will there be any security policy in windows2008 will prevent it to be writing?

Comment: If you log in as the SQL Server Agent service account (assuming you can) are you able to run the bat file?  Are you using xp_cmdshell to execute the bat file or a command step in your job?  Do you have a "Run As" set for the job step?

Comment: Hi Kenneth, when i try to run the batch file from the command it is executing with out an error; but when i try to run from the sql server xp_cmdshell'' getting access denied error

Comment: Kenneth's answer has some good advice. Keep in mind that you also need to look at the NTFS _and_ share permissions. The more restrictive of the two permissions sets will apply.

Answer (score 2):

If you are running the batch file through `xp_cmdshell` you are using a different set of permissions.  Here is the [BOL entry for `xp_cmdshell`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175046%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Basically though if you are running it as a sysadmin then `xp_cmdshell` uses the service account for SQL Server, not the service account for the Agent.  If you are not running it as a sysadmin then it uses a proxy account.  The proxy account is stored in credential called `##xp_cmdshell_proxy_account##`.